# List posts when custom field is specific value

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to output a list of titles from of a specific post type based on whenever the "Style & Art" select box has been chosen within those posts.

The below code doesn't seem to output anything other than the opening and closing ul tags.

However, if I remove the meta_query array then it lists all post types.

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'profiles',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'you_may_also_like',
                'value' => 'Style & Art'
            )
        )
    );

    query_posts($args);

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo '<li>';
            the_title();
        echo '</li>';
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query(); ?>
</ul>
```

I need to be able to filter them based on a certain criteria but not having any luck at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is the value' => 'Style & Art'. I doubt that 'Style & Art' is the value, but instead simply the label of the check box. Try the following:

```
    array(
        'key' => 'you_may_also_like',
        'value' => 'true'
    )
```